# How to concatenate thousands of Pandas DataFrames efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a folder `/data/csvs` which contains ~7000 CSV files each with ~600 lines. Each CSV has a name which contains a timestamp that needs to be preserved e.g. `/data/csvs/261121.csv`, `/data/csvs/261122.csv` (`261121` being 26/11/21 today's date).

I need to:

1. Load each CSV.
2. Add a column in which the timestamp can be saved so I know which file the data came from. The time increases by half a second each row so this row also shows the hour/minute/second/microseconds.
3. Combine the rows into one table which will span a month of data.
4. Ideally I'd like the final product to be a DataFrame.

Currently this is what I'm doing:

```
    files = os.listdir('/data/csvs')
    csv_names = []
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name[-4:] == '.csv':
            csv_names.append(file_name)

    to_process = len(csv_names)
    for i, csv_name in enumerate(csv_names):
        df = pd.read_csv(f'{csv_folder_path}/{file_name}')
        df = timestamp(df, csv_name)

        to_process = to_process-1

        if i == 0:
            concat_df = df
            concat_df.to_feather(path=processed_path)
        else:
            concat_df = pd.concat([concat_df, df])

            if to_process % 100 == 0:
                saved_df = pd.read_feather(path=processed_path)
                concat_df = pd.concat([saved_df, concat_df])
                concat_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
                concat_df.to_feather(path=processed_path)
```

I'm loading in each CSV as a DataFrame, adding the timestamp column and concatenating the CSVs 100 at a time (because I thought this would reduce memory usage) and then saving 100 CSVs at a time to a large DataFrame feather file. This is really slow and uses loads of memory.

What is a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could be more efficient loading your files using `glob`. This saves you iterating over all the files and checking whether the file-extension is ".csv"

```
import glob

src = '/data/csvs'
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*.csv"))
```

Then, read all files into a df and add them to a generator, in the same step assigning the basename of the file to a column named timestamp

```
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f).assign(timestamp=os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0]) for f in files)
```

And finally concatenate the dfs into one

```
csv_data = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

Hope this helped! I have used a process like this for large amounts of data and found it efficient enough.

Comment: This works very nicely, thanks.